# How to create a Comparison<> on the fly?

Tags: c#, reflection, comparison, reflection.emit

I want to create a Comparison<>-Delegate via reflection in code. I have this:

```
var returnType = typeof (Int32);
var parameters = typeof(Comparison<>).GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
AssemblyName aname = new AssemblyName("MyEmissions");
AssemblyBuilder assemBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aname, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder modBuilder = assemBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule", "MyEmissions.dll");

TypeBuilder tb = modBuilder.DefineType("Widget", TypeAttributes.Public);
MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod("Echo", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

mb.SetSignature(returnType, null, null, parameters, null, null);

ILGenerator gen = mb.GetILGenerator();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var foo = MulticastDelegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Comparison<>), mb);
```

The last line throws a ArgumentException: MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object. I'm new to reflection and emit and have a feeling that only a small step is missing!?

Edit:

I'm not bound to creating a new Assembly - I also tried DynamicMethod:

```
var returnType = typeof (Int32);
var parameters = typeof(Comparison<>).GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();
var handler = new DynamicMethod("", returnType, parameters);
var generator = handler.GetILGenerator();

foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
    var localVariable = generator.DeclareLocal(parameter);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, localVariable);
}

if (returnType != null)
{
    var returnValue = generator.DeclareLocal(returnType);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, returnValue);
}

generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

handler.CreateDelegate(typeof(Comparison<>));
```

Throws a BadImageFormatException :/

---

Solution:

```
var returnType = typeof (Int32);
var methodParameters = typeof(Comparison<>).GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType.ToString()).ToArray();

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
AssemblyName aname = new AssemblyName("MyEmissions");
AssemblyBuilder assemBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aname, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder modBuilder = assemBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule", "MyEmissions.dll");

TypeBuilder tb = modBuilder.DefineType("Widget", TypeAttributes.Public);
MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod("Echo", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

GenericTypeParameterBuilder[] typeParameters = mb.DefineGenericParameters(methodParameters);

mb.SetReturnType(returnType);
mb.SetParameters(typeParameters);

ILGenerator gen = mb.GetILGenerator();
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var dt = tb.CreateType();

var mi = dt.GetMethod("Echo");
var gm = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

var parameter = MulticastDelegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Comparison<string>), gm);
```

Comment: I *suspect* you need to call `TypeBuilder.CreateType`, and then get the method from that. Do you definitely *need* to create a new assembly like this though? I suspect `DynamicMethod` would be a better fit for you.

Comment: check this post in stack overflow may help you [Reflection.Emit: How to convert MethodBuilder to RuntimeMethodInfo reliably?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031183/reflection-emit-how-to-convert-methodbuilder-to-runtimemethodinfo-reliably

Comment: Can you provide some psuedo C# of what you are trying to emit?

Comment: @JonSkeet: You suspect correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others already pointed out some errors in your code. But there is another bigger issue: you're trying to create generic method and unbound generic delegate.

In the case of `DynamicMethod`, [you can't create generic method at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788618/dynamicmethod-with-generic-type-parameters). In the case of dynamic assembly, it is possible, but you have to use [`DefineGenericParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.definegenericparameters.aspx).

If you managed to create a generic method somehow, you can't create an unbound generic delegate. That is, you can't create a delegate of type `Comparison<T>`, like you're trying to do. You have to substitute some specific type for `T`. So, for example, you could create `Comparison<int>`.

Also, I find twiddling with CIL quite hard, especially if you don't have much experience with it. It might be much easier to create your delegate by creating a `Expression` and compiling that.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second example.

What you are doing is correct. BUT the code you emit is incorrect. That is why you are getting the `BadImageFormatException`.

Currently, you have values left on the stack left by:

```
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, localVariable);
```

To remedy, either not load them or pop them from the stack again.

Comment: Hmm - if I comment out the foreach-loop putting variables on the stack, a BatImageFormatException will still be thrown.

Comment: @PapaMufflon, the exception message is “The signature is incorrect.” That's because you can't create generic method using `DynamicMethod`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @svick: Interesting :)  (Good spot +1 for answer)